# Docker parameters work with 'docker run' but not with compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The parameters used in compose file don't work. For example, when I run the commands below, folders on my host machine are not mounted to the container.

```
docker compose -p devenv -f .\compose-devenv.yml build
docker run -i -t devenv-devenv
```

However, when I run the command below, I can see the folders in the container.

`docker run -i -t -v "C:/:/home/Projects/" devenv-devenv`

Also, ports and cuda device are not working in the container too when I use compose file. How can I build container from the compose file correctly?

Dockerfile.devenv

```
# get our base pytorch container image from torch official docker hub repository
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.13.1-cuda11.6-cudnn8-runtime

# Define work directory.
WORKDIR /home/Projects/

### Install additional libraries
COPY requirements.txt /home/Projects/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

compose-devenv.yml

```
services:
  devenv:
    environment:
      MYUSERDATA: "${USER}"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.devenv
    ports:
      - "7776:22" # ssh
      - "7777:7777" # gdb server
      - "8888:8888" # Jupyter Notebook Server
      - "6006:6006" # Tensorboard Server
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              capabilities: [gpu]
    volumes:
      - "C:/:/home/Projects/"
```